# Please help me with RESTful http caching

Tags: api, rest, http, caching, client-server

I am developing a mobile application that loads the data from our **REST- Server.** For example, this list of products . Products are stored on the server in a database table and has the following structure:

```
| id | updatet_at          | name  | price |
|----|---------------------|-------|-------|
| 1  | 23.08.2015 06:00:00 | bread | 10    |
| 2  | 24.08.2015 12:00:00 | butter| 55    |
| 3  | 24.08.2015 12:00:00 | cheese| 180   |
| 4  | 24.08.2015 18:00:00 | sugar | 80    |
```

My goal is to understand the standard caching scheme. Now my caching works this way:

1)

```
GET /api/v1/products HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: 24.08.2015 18:00:00
Content-Type: application/json

[
  { "id" : "1", "name" : "bread", "price" : 10 },
  { "id" : "2", "name" : "butter", "price" : 55 },
  { "id" : "3", "name" : "cheese", "price" : 180 },
  { "id" : "4", "name" : "sugar", "price" : 80 }
]
```

After the server gave me the answer I caches data in the same table in the local database with the only difference, I put `updated_at` each element == `Last-Modified` came with the server. So my local database as follows:

```
| id | updatet_at          | name  | price |
|----|---------------------|-------|-------|
| 1  | 24.08.2015 18:00:00 | bread | 10    |
| 2  | 24.08.2015 18:00:00 | butter| 55    |
| 3  | 24.08.2015 18:00:00 | cheese| 180   |
| 4  | 24.08.2015 18:00:00 | sugar | 80    |
```

Then I send the following request :

2)

```
GET /api/v1/products HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
If-Modified-Since: 24.08.2015 18:00:00


HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified

[Empty body]
```

The request header If-Modified-Since I was substitute the latest date from the field updated_at, because Server data is not updated or added, the response is returned from the server 304. Let the server added one entry and one existing changed:

```
| id | updatet_at          | name  | price |
|----|---------------------|-------|-------|
| 1  | 23.08.2015 06:00:00 | bread | 10    |
| 2  | 24.08.2015 12:00:00 | butter| 55    |
| 3  | 24.08.2015 12:00:00 | cheese| 180   |
| 4  | 26.08.2015 09:00:00 | sugar | 90    |
| 5  | 26.08.2015 08:00:00 | flour | 60    |
```

Again, I send an inquiry

3)

```
GET /api/v1/products HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
If-Modified-Since: 24.08.2015 18:00:00


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: 26.08.2015 09:00:00
Content-Type: application/json

[
  { "id" : "4", "name" : "sugar", "price" : 90 },
  { "id" : "5", "name" : "flour", "price" : 60 }
]
```

After receiving this response, I change the record with id == 4 , in accordance with the answer , and add a new entry . Both of these records I put `updated_at == Last-Modified` response from the appropriate server . My implementation of caching I was completely satisfied until I entered selections on parameters `GET` request . Let's say I cleaned a local cache and sends the following query:

4)

```
GET /api/v1/products?min_price=60&max_price=100 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: 26.08.2015 09:00:00
Content-Type: application/json

[
  { "id" : "4", "name" : "sugar", "price" : 90 },
  { "id" : "5", "name" : "flour", "price" : 60 }
]
```

Here, in the GET parameters string I pass min_price = 60 and max_price = 100 . The server according to my request, selects among existing elements , and gives me 2 suitable according caching scheme , he substitutes the maximum value updated_at among the selected elements in the Last-Modified. My client application caches data come . The local database is as follows:

```
| id | updatet_at          | name  | price |
|----|---------------------|-------|-------|
| 4  | 26.08.2015 09:00:00 | sugar | 90    |
| 5  | 26.08.2015 09:00:00 | flour | 60    |
```

Now, when I will send a request for all products:

5)

```
GET /api/v1/products HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
If-Modified-Since: 26.08.2015 09:00:00


HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified

[Empty body]
```

It turns out that this situation can not I get older ( with less `updated_at`) products due to the fact that I already give maximum `updated_at`, so my caching scheme broke down. Prompt how to use standard HTTP caching for dynamic data?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to request individual resources, you can use the individual `updated_at` value. But if you want to request the whole collection using `If-Modified-Since`, you need to separately track the last time you requested the whole collection. Otherwise you're going to run into exactly the issue you're seeing, because individual records may be updated indpendently of the whole collection.

Pretend you were using `ETag`s instead of the last modified date. You wouldn't send up the `ETag` for an individual record and expect to get back the correct collection results, would you?

Another reasonable option is to request the collection without an ETag, and then do individual GETs to retrieve the resources, sending up `If-Modified-Since` for each individual resource. That approach may or may not be too noisy for you.